# How to get value of form with same class

Tags: jquery, html

i allready asked same sort question and learned to use class in this sort case.

Now i have another problem with a hidden input, it shows the first value of the input cant get the value of the entered textarea.

I allready tried with `name`, `id` and `class` but i will always get the first value, how to solve this one

Here a JsFiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/96muj4wx/

Code

**HTML**

```
<form class=replyForm>
    <input type=hidden class=message-reply-statusId value=1 >
    <textarea class='beantwoorden reply' placeholder='Write a reaction...'></textarea>
</form>
<form class=replyForm>
    <input type=hidden class=message-reply-statusId value=2 >
    <textarea class='reply' placeholder='Write a reaction...'></textarea>
</form>
    <div id=value></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var replyForm = $('.replyForm');

    replyForm.on('keydown', function(evt) {

        var key = (evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which);

        // get the reply from selected form
        replyField = $(this).find("textarea");
        replyVal = replyField.val();
        replyStatusId = $('.message-reply-statusId');
        replyStatusId = replyStatusId.val();
        if (key === 13) {
            // prevent enter, line down
            evt.preventDefault();

            // test, append reply val to document
            // delete this line
            $('#value').append(replyStatusId + '<br>');

            if (replyVal) {
                console.log( replyStatusId)
                // do ajax stuff
                // clear field
                replyField.val('');
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
replyStatusId = $('.message-reply-statusId');
```

with :

```
replyStatusId = $(this).find('.message-reply-statusId');
```

Comment: Thanks i was totally forgot about the this function. Thank you very much !

Comment: You did it just fine two lines above ;)